# Template specialization for a range of values

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I wish to write a template structure `foo` such that `foo<N>::value_type` is the nearest sized integer (rounding up) to `N`.  For example `foo<32>::value_type => uint32_t`, `foo<33>::value_type => uint64_t` and `foo<72>::value_type => uint64_t`.

To do this I need an elegant means of providing partial specializations of `foo` for a range of values, e.g, `1 <= N <= 8` to return uint8_t and so on and so fourth.  Is there a means of accomplishing this without having to specialise everything from 0 to 64.

Comment: There won't be a direct way (like Mark said), but maybe some clever template metaprogramming trick. Nice question, waiting to see the answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
template<size_t N> struct select { typedef uint64_t result; };
template<> struct select<0> { typedef uint8_t result; };
template<> struct select<1> { typedef uint16_t result; };
template<> struct select<2> { typedef uint32_t result; };

template<size_t N>
struct foo
{
    enum{D = (N > 32 ? 3 : (N > 16 ? 2 : (N > 8 ? 1 : 0)))};

    typedef typename select<D>::result value_type;

    value_type value;
};
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can use `std::conditional`:

```
typedef 
    typename std::conditional<(N > 32), uint64_t,
    typename std::conditional<(N > 16), uint32_t,
    typename std::conditional<(N > 8), uint16_t, uint8_t>
    ::type>::type>::type value_type;
```

You can decide which one is less readable.

Comment: Great answer. Shouldn't the enum be `enum{D = (N > 32 ? 3 : (N > 16 ? 2 : (N > 8 ? 1 : 0)))};`, though? Here's it working: http://ideone.com/OgXaz

Comment: Oh wow, I've done this in the past, but this is _much_ simpler than my version!  Though mine had bool(1), char(2-8),  ..., long long(33-64), and void(65+)

Comment: @filipe Thank you for the complete test, you are right!

Answer (score 7):

@hansmaad answer is a nice answer, but I would prefer to use (guess what?!) [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html):

```
boost::uint_t<N>::least // N: bits
```

> The smallest, built-in, unsigned integral type with at least N bits.
>   The parameter should be a positive number. A compile-time error
>   results if the parameter is larger than the number of bits in the
>   largest integer type.

Comment: Very cute, even more so as I am using boost in my project, but it does not handle the case of foo<72>::value_type resolving to the largest available integer.

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters need to be concrete, so I don't think there's any way to avoid specializing for each required value.